# Changes in shape in Special Relativity

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames

I know that there is quite a lot of material on length contraction in special relativity (SR), but I am currently confused with the following case that I have not seen discussed before.

Imagine that Sara is inside a train that is parked at the station. And imagine that Sara has two rulers, one always aligned horizontally (along X) and one aligned vertically (along Y).   Sara then notices that the window in her cabin is perfectly square with 1-meter sides according to the two rulers. Now imagine that there is also an observer outside the train, who also has an X and Y ruler, and who also measures the window to have 1-meter sides.

Sara goes to sleep, and in the meantime, the train accelerates quite a lot. When she wakes up, the train is now moving at constant speed at nearly the speed of light with respect to the station. I know that for the external observer, the train and all the stuff inside of it have been contracted along the X-axis (the axis of motion). So for the person outside, the train's windows are no longer perfectly square because the base is contracted while the height is the same (so they look like a generic rectangle). However, I am confused about what shape Sara sees for the window after she wakes up.

On the one hand, since Sara is moving together with the window, their relative speed is zero and no contraction should arise (this is the proper length of the base of the window). On the other hand, the Sara who is waking up, and the Sara before going to sleep are effectively using different frames of reference, so I could see an argument saying that they can't be seen exactly the very same X-length for the window. I understand if someone says that the "two Saras" both see that the X ruler indicates "1 meter" for the base of the window because the ruler contracts together with the base, and so the X measurements will always indicate the same outcomes (if it indicates "1 meter" at the station, it will indicate the same after Sara wakes up). But would not Sara (after waking up) be able to see that the X ruler looks shorter with respect to the Y ruler even though both indicate "1 meter"? And so would not Sara see the window to be not perfectly square? In short, will the two Saras see their windows to be squares or not?

I guess part of what I am trying to understand is if there is a way to compare the proper length of different frames (such as the proper length of the base of the window when the train was parked, and its proper length when the train is moving). I know the proper length is not supposed to change, but I am not sure if this is just because the ruler also contracts in the same way as the object and so measurements of the proper length give the same results, or because of something deeper (something not having to do with the fact that the ruler also contracts).  Thanks!

Comment: The deeper idea is simply that an [inertial frame of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_frame_of_reference) can always be considered as being at rest.

Answer (score 3):

The proper length of the window is the length in any frame in which the window is not moving. Before Sara goes to sleep she is in a frame in which the train is not moving, and when she wakes she is in a frame in which the train is not moving. Provided Sara continues to be at rest relative to the train, the window will always have the same proper length in her frame of reference.

Remember that there is no absolute velocity. Your erroneous supposition- that perhaps the window's length only seems the same because the ruler has also contracted- would imply that there is an absolute state of rest which is the only one in which the window and the ruler both have a 'real' length- which is nonsense. It also assumes that if there were such an absolute frame then it just happened to be the frame of the platform, which is nonsense squared. The proper length is the real, genuine, undistorted, honest-to-goodness length of the object.

Length contraction is an effect that occurs when the length of an object in a frame in which it is stationary (ie its proper length) is compared with the length of the object in a frame through which it is moving inertially. It arises from the relativity of simultaneity.

Comment: Thanks. This certainly helps! But just to clarify, I did not assume that " if there were such an absolute frame then it just happened to be the frame of the platform". I was simply wondering if the proper length as measured in one frame F must always be the same as the proper length as measured in another arbitrary inertial frame in which the object and the observer are moving. If the object was accelerated to a new frame and it did not break, I was wondering if its "new" proper length is just the same as it was before it was accelerated.

Comment: "The proper length of the window is the length in any frame in which the window is not moving."   Yes, but of course this proper length can change if the window is compressed or stretched, as might or might not be the case depending on the details of how the acceleration takes place.

Comment: You are missing the point that the observer and object are always at rest, as far as they are concerned,  if they are in an inertial frame, so the observer will always see the true length of the object, unaltered by any relativistic effects. As WillO points out, if you permanently distort the object as a consequence of accelerating it, you might change its length, but that has nothing whatsoever to do with relativity.

Comment: Marco:  I'd take issue with your "nothing whatsoever to do with relativity".   Pre-acceleration, the train is longer in the station frame than in the moving-train frame.  Post-acceleration, the train is longer in the moving-train frame than in the station frame.   Therefore *the acceleration must have distorted the train's length in at least one frame*.   That's a significant consequence of relativity.

Comment: Moreover, this presents an instructive "paradox" in the same sense that the twin paradox is instructive:  How can the acceleration distort length in one frame and not the other?  Answer:  Accelerations of both ends, simultaneous in one frame, must be non-simultaneous in the other.  That too illustrates a significant consequence of relativity.

Comment: @WillO you are arguing with me at cross purposes. I said that the train always maintains the same length in whatever its rest frame happens to be. Clearly in any other frame in which the train is not at rest, its length will be different.

Comment: You can accelerate a car by hitting it with a wrecking ball, and that will change its length, but it has nothing to do with relativity.

Comment: " I said that the train always maintains the same length in whatever its rest frame happens to be."  1) If this is true, it is surely true for reasons that have nothing to do with relativity and much to do with the materials the train happens to be made out of, which would seem to be as off-topic as your wrecking ball.  2)  Even the wrecking ball is on-topic:  It accelerates one end of the train before the other, and the time difference between those two accelerations accounts for the length change.  The length changes differently in different frames because of relativity of simultaneity.

Comment: @WillO you are still missing my point. In any inertial frame the train is at rest relative to an observer riding on it, and therefore no relativistic effects- specifically no length contraction- will be apparent to that observer. That was the point of my answer.

Comment: Marco:  You are of course right about that (as you are pretty much always).   I am disagreeing only on the subjective question of what has "nothing to do with relativity".  The ratio "length of train in frame A"/"length of train in frame B" is different post-acceleration than it is pre-acceleration, and you can find many posts on this site asking how that can possibly be.  The answer is that the time delay between the left-side and right-side accelerations is different in different frames, and it seems to me that that has everything to do with relativity.

Comment: @willo, indeed- I agree with you. Perhaps I should have been clearer in my answer to avoid the ambiguity you have pointed out. If I get a chance, I will update it. All the best!

Answer (score 1):

Unless the window gets damaged during the acceleration it will remain square in the frame of the cabin. Sarah's going to sleep is irrelevant to the window.

Comment: But does it matter that the "frame of the cabin" changes due to the acceleration? the initial "frame of the cabin" was given by the station, but the "new frame of the cabin" is moving with respect to the station. (I know Sara does not have magic powers while she sleeps ;) )

Comment: @curiousphilosopher "does it matter that the "frame of the cabin" changes due to the acceleration?" Only if the window gets damaged in the acceleration, as I stated in the answer.

Comment: it would be very helpful if you please comment on my thread with WillO (see below). We seem to be interpreting your answer differently.

Answer (score 1):

The horizontal length of the window of the moving train is greater in the moving train frame than in the platform frame.

The ratio of those lengths to each other is determined by relativity.  The ratio of those lengths to the original 1 meter can be anything at all depending on how the train got up to speed (e. g.  whether the front started moving before the back or after the back in the platform frame).

Comment: But what about the ratio between the height and the base of the window in the moving train as measured by someone in the moving train compared to the same ratio for the train at the station? Are they the same? Are both ratios equal to 1 (as a square)?

Comment: @curiousphilosopher : The height of the window is 1 meter in all the relevant frames.

Comment: Yes, but is the base the same? I am wondering about the shape (the ratio between the height and the base).

Comment: @curiousphilosopher :  I answered this question, so I'm not sure why you're repeating it.

Comment: To repeat what I've already said:   While the train is sitting in the station, the width of the window is $1$ meter in the station frame and $\beta$ meters in the moving-train frame, where $\beta<1$ depends only on the velocity of the moving train.  Once the train is up to speed, the width of the window is $x$ in the moving-train frame and $\beta x$ in the station frame, where $x$ can be anything at all (subject to the window not breaking, per @Dale's answer).  In particular $x$ can be greater or less than $1$ meter.  The height of the window is always $1$ meter in both frames.

Comment: Without more information, nothing more can be said.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but the reason I keep asking is that your answer is different from the answer by @Dale, so I am not sure I really follow. Dale says that Sara sees a square in both cases. But you do not seem to say that, or at least not directly. You say that the width is x in the moving frame, where x can be greater or less than 1. And you say that the height is the same. So it follows from what you say that Sara does not necessarily see a square in the moving-train frame (contrary to what Dale says).

Comment: I am sure that @Dale and I do not fundamentally disagree.   I am assuming that the window is infinitely stretchable, which seems to me to be consistent with the usual sort of simplifying assumptions we make in relativity (like the feasability of instant accelerations, and the ability of travelers to survive those instant accelerations).  Dale is more focused on the real-world fact that if you try to stretch a window very far, it will break.   I agree that real-world windows are not very stretchable; I expect Dale will agree that insofar as windows are stretchable my answer is right.

Comment: You did in fact assume that Sara could survive an acceleration to nearly the speed of light in a very short time.  It seems to me that in any version of the world that is sufficiently simplified for that to happen, windows are going to be pretty stretchable.

Comment: You do seem to fundamentally disagree. @Dale says that if the window does not break, it will still look like a square for Sara after the acceleration takes place. You are saying that if it does not break, it does not look like a square anymore (as x does not need to equal 1 meter).

Comment: Dale is assuming that if the window stretches without breaking, it will snap back to something like its "natural" size.  This is likely true in the real world, and false in the world where our usual simplified relativity stories take place.  In the real world, you can't bring the train close to light speed in the first place.

Comment: In other words, I am saying that $x$ can be anything.  Dale is saying that if $x$ is very far from $1$, then the window breaks.  Which means (per Dale) that if the window doesn't break, $x$ must be very close to $1$.

Comment: I am assuming a window with something like glass. If you push on it too hard during acceleration then you can crush it. If you pull it to hard during acceleration then you can rupture it. If it neither crushes nor ruptures then it stayed within its elastic limit during the acceleration, so it never substantially deviated from its original size in its proper frame.

Comment: Thanks, Dale. Yeah, I mean we do not need to assume a very big acceleration. We can modify the case so that the spaceship accelerates at 10 m/s^2 for 10 months. At the end of 10 months, it will reach more than 80% of the speed of light. Or make the acceleration even smaller and the time bigger. @WillO, would you say x=1 in a case where the acceleration is small but the final velocity is big?

Comment: @curiousphilosopher:  "@WillO, would you say x=1 in a case where the acceleration is small but the final velocity is big?"   No.   $x=1$ when the acceleration takes place in a way that doesn't destroy the window.   This has nothing to do with the magnitude of the accceleration, but with the *difference* in the magnitudes of the acceleration at the two ends of the window (though you need to be careful about how to interpret this, because you need to think about the magnitudes *at the same time* in a series of appropriately chosen frames).